# No such module error in Swift after Cocoapod

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, dependency-management

Using Swift5 and Xcode-10.2.

After a Cocoapods install usage, I cannot import the Swift module - Why ???

And yes, there is plenty of posts out there that give ideas why. But none of them worked for me so far.

Here is my pod file:

```
project 'M.xcodeproj'
workspace 'MyApp.xcworkspace'
platform :ios, '11.0'
inhibit_all_warnings!

source 'https://github.com/artsy/Specs.git'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

use_frameworks!

def shared_pods
  pod 'SwiftSVG'
end

target 'MyApp' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    shared_pods
end
```

[image: t af]

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the build folder? **SHIFT + COMMAND + K**

Comment: yes, I did that but nope - did not help...

Comment: Try to reinstall your pods by running this commands:
`sudo gem install cocoapods-clean`
`pod deintegrate`
`pod clean`
`pod install`, sometimes this solves some Pod's issues

Comment: I am not much further. However, I realised that one of my 7 Targets works. (most likely it did work all along). But what about the other 6 Targets. Why would another Xcode Target not compile and still show this silly message "module not found". Do you have any idea here ? (I have the same Framework Search Paths for all the 7 Targets). Is there any other parameter I need to set ?

Comment: Finally found it: The pod file did not have all the Targets - therefore the Header- and Framework Search Paths were not correct.

Answer (score -1):

Silly me!

It turned out that my Podfile was missing Project-Targets:

```
project 'MyApp.xcodeproj'
workspace 'MyApp.xcworkspace'
platform :ios, '11.0'
inhibit_all_warnings!

source 'https://github.com/artsy/Specs.git'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

use_frameworks!

def shared_pods
  # pod 'SVGKit'
  pod 'SwiftSVG'
end

target 'MyApp' do
    shared_pods
end

target 'MyApp Beta' do
    shared_pods
end

target 'MyApp Stage' do
    shared_pods
end

target 'MyApp Dev' do
    shared_pods
end

target 'MyApp DevPatch' do
    shared_pods
end

target 'MyApp Test2' do
    shared_pods
end

target 'MyApp TestPatch' do
    shared_pods
end

# target 'MyAppTests' do
#     shared_pods
# end

# target 'MyAppUITests' do
#     shared_pods
# end
```